# how to select column which is not in group by sentence in hive?

Tags: hadoop

There's a table `test` which has 3 columns: `id1, id2 ,id3`

In MySQL, I can use

```
select id1, id2, id3 
from test 
group by id1, id2;
```

to get the different `id1, id2` and the first `id3` in every group.

For example: the data in table test as follow

```
id1 id2 id3 
 1   1   1
 1   2   1
 1   2   2
 2   2   2
```

the result would be:

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
2 2 2
```

but in hive, there is an error

> Expression not in GROUP BY key 'id3'

What can I use in hive? I just want to group by id1,id2 and get the first row of id3 .

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select id1,id2,id3
from 
(
select id1,id2,id3,ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition BY id1,id2) as rnum
from test ) t
where rnum=1;
```

output

```
1   1   1
1   2   1
2   2   2
```